# having trouble understanding :multiple => true in a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, multipleselection

I am very new to Ruby on Rails, I have inherited control of a Ruby/Rails web based database(created by another) for generating and tracking engineering functions. I use Aptana IDE.

My issue is that I am trying to use a form helper to select multiple values for our "product lines". I use 10 check boxes, and I get the correct output of one value if I don't use ":multiple => true".

See output image:

[image: no multiple select]

works as intended

```
<%= f.check_box :product_line, {:class => "field"}, "A9", false %> A9
```

(10 times with different values where "A9" is, so there are ten checkbox's total, image shows "A7" check box returned)

By simply adding the :multiple => true, the output changes as seen in the image below:

see output image:

[image: multiple select]

returns too much

```
<%= f.check_box :product_line, {:class => "field", :multiple => true}, "A9", false %> A9
```

Why are all of those "-" added before the output only if the multiple selection is made? I want it to return only comma separated values of the checkbox, i.e. " A9, A7"

```
PRODUCT_LINES = [ "A9", "A7", "AG", "AF", "S3", "Legacy", "K/Kpro", "EMW", "HD", "Non-Metallic" ]
```

other ideas:
Can I loop through an array of :product_line to get what im looking for instead?
I was also playing with the multiple selection in a drop down menu but could never select a second option before the drop down returned and only selected my first selection.

Comment: I salute your passion brother. You are doing Rails development on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are all of those "-" added before the output only if multiple
>   selection is made?

From [the docs (read the Gotcha)](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) when multiple is set to true all selections will be stored in an array of product_lines but un-selected check_boxes will also be reserve as an empty strings in the sent pararms so for the result you are seeing product_lines would be something like:

```
product_lines = ["", "", "", "A9", "A7"]
```

> Can I loop through an array of :product_line to get what im looking
>   for instead?

Well, actually this takes us right to the problem in using `multiple: true` in your code.

The process explained in (1) above is how the check_box_tag was designed, the problem you are seeing is in presentation probably in your ECN#show. Without reviewing code there i am only guessing but usually it's something like:

```
<%= @ecn.product_lines.join('-') %>
```

which should be

```
<%= @ecn.product_lines.reject(&:blank?).join(',') %>
```

where: `reject(&:blank?)` to get rid of empty strings then joining with commas as you need

*Hope this helps!*